# Razor @Url.Action returns with the optional id parameter to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it intended that the @Url.Action method returns the current url if the user is currently within the controller and action that the parameters reference?

I have a simple setup for our controllers.

```
OrderableTest/Details/Id
ResultableTest/Details/Id
```

If I call `@Url.Action("Details", "Orderable")` from the home controller `(Home/Index)` or from the `Resultable/Details` I will get the proper URL saved to a javascript variable `("/Orderable/Details")`. If, however, I am on a Details page then the id gets included in the url. For example, I am on the page `Orderable/Details/12345` and I call `@Url.Action("Details", "Orderable")`, instead of getting `"/Orderable/Details"` I get `"/Orderable/Details/12345"`. Is this the intended functionality?

Routing map is default.

Javascript as requested:

```
var orderableDetailUrl = '@Url.Action("Details", "Orderable")';
var resultableDetailUrl = '@Url.Action("Details", "Resultable")';
alert(orderableDetailUrl);
alert(resultableDetailUrl);
```

Comment: it would help if you show your javascript and describe what you want to achieve

Comment: I never had encountered this behavior, are you sure you use it as intended?

Comment: the UrlHelper methods use the context information, like the current page route data, to create the urls. So, yes, that's intended behavior. As Dimitry says, so us your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by @JotaBe in the comments above, the UrlHelper uses the context information. Thus an @Url.Action called for the page that you're currently on will also include optional id/parameters.

To get around this, you can pass in a blank optional parameter to the method. For my problem above, it was solved with the following code

```
var resultableDetailUrl = '@Url.Action("Details", "Resultable", new { id = "" })';
var orderableDetailUrl = '@Url.Action("Details", "Orderable", new { id = "" })';
```

Which both will properly return /Orderable/Details/ and /Resultable/Details/ regardless of which page the user is currently on.

Comment: very nice! this helped me a lot